# Autoincrement id of an object in array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to store array of an objects in postgresql. Structure of object should looks like

```
{
  "id": 1
  "title": "XYZ",
  "content": "abcabc"
}
```

My question is how to automatically increment an id ?

Structure of the table looks like

```
user_id | user_name | notes
```

The notes column should store the array of objects (notes).
What is the best way to do that, what is the best data type ( json, jsonb, 
 json[], jsonb[] )?
I'm using flask and postgresql (11).

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createsequence.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate table:

```
create table user_notes (
    user_notes_id serial primary key,
    user_id int references users(user_id),
    title text,
    content text,
    created_at timestamp default now()
);
```

If you want to enumerate the notes for a particular user, use `row_number()`:

```
select un.*, row_number() over (partition by un.user_id order by un.user_notes_id) as seqnum
from user_notes un
where un.user_id = ?;
```

Comment: How I can update data ? I mean how query should looks

Comment: @MarcinKrysik . . . You don't need to update anything.  Just insert rows into `user_notes` and the `serial` column is updated automatically.

Comment: It creates a small mess in the table. Is it the only way ? I wanted to assign notes to the user.

Comment: @MarcinKrysik . . . This is the typical data structure for  storing notes created by a user in SQL.  You *can* use arrays, of course, but when you update an array you have to update the entire array at once -- which takes progressively more time as the array gets bigger.